# Converting Native C++ code to Java

Tags: java, android, c++

I am converting a Native C++ Function into Java but stuck at some point.

Here is the Native Code which causing the problem for me.

```
for(int x=0; x < inputMat.cols; x++)
{
    for(int y=0; y < inputMat.rows; y++)
    {
        for(int c=0; c < 4; c++)
        {
            grayMat.at<cv::Vec4b>(y,x)[c] = (grayMat.at<cv::Vec4b>(y,x)[c] == 255 ? 255 : std::min(255,grayMat.at<cv::Vec4b>(y,x)[c]*255/(255-grayMat.at<cv::Vec4b>(y,x)[c]))); 
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my converted version of above code in Java

```
for(int x = 0; x < inputMat.cols(); x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < inputMat.rows(); y++){

            double data[] = new double[4];
            for(int c = 0; c < 4; c++){

                data[c] = grayMat.get(y,x)[c] == 255 ? 255 Math.min(255,grayMat.get(y,x)[c]*255/(255-grayMat.get(y,x)[c]));
                grayMat.put(y,x,data[c]);

            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting the following error:

> Process: covariance.com.imagefilter, PID: 11660
>       java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Provided data element number (1) should be multiple of the Mat channels count (4)
>           at org.opencv.core.Mat.put(Mat.java:954)
>           at covariance.com.imagefilter.MainActivity.cartoonMatConversion(MainActivity.java:358)
>           at covariance.com.imagefilter.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:47)
>           at covariance.com.imagefilter.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:91)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6291)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24931)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)

**Note grayMat contains 4 colors BGRA**

Comment: Your C++ code uses `cv::Vect4b` which denotes a vector of 4-byte elements.  I assume your BGRA format is 1 byte apiece for the B,G,R, and A channels.  In your Java code, you are using `double[]`.  Use `byte[]` instead and then call `put(int row, int col, byte[] data)` on the entire `byte[]` array.

Comment: Move the put outside the innermost loop, and use `grayMat.put(y,x,data)`.

Comment: Thank you @AndyTurner Solved. Please add it as answer so I can accpt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your call:

```
grayMat.put(y,x,data[c]);
```

For one thing it's inside the innermost loop; for another, you're only setting a single value, when 4 are needed (as the error says).

Move it outside the loop, and pass the entire array:

```
for(int c = 0; c < 4; c++){
  data[c] = ...
}
grayMat.put(y,x,data);
```